Set a field/entry type to used by plugin field
I have a plugin that uses other fields and entry types. When you go into the Entry types overview "Used by" says "no usage" on these fields. How do I register the usage when I save my field settings?
My settings use this field:
   $select_fields = Cp::checkboxSelectFieldHtml([
        'label'        => Craft::t( 'app', 'Allowed Fields' ),
        'instructions' => Craft::t( 'app', '' ),
        'id'           => 'my_fields',
        'name'         => 'my_fields',
        'values'       => $this->my_fields,
        'options'      => $options,
    ]);


"Used by" for fields counts field instances in field layouts, listed by field layout provider. E.g. if an instance of a field appears in a field layout, that usage's layout provider (i.e. entry type, asset volume, global set etc.) will be listed for the field in question.
"Used by" for entry types counts usages for that entry type in sections and Matrix fields.
It's currently not possible to register other "usages" for fields and entry types beyond this, but it'd be cool if Craft emitted events like EVENT_DEFINE_FIELD_USAGES and EVENT_DEFINE_ENTRY_TYPE when building the usages list – you might consider making a feature request for something like that.
